# Create a class for Google API wallet in PHP

Tags: php, web, google-api, grpc, android-pay

I allow myself to ask a question here because I really can't find the solution and I hope to find some help here!
So first, I understood how the Wallet API of google works, I created a class to test with the information, everything works perfectly, but now I would like to be able to create a unique class for each visitor with his information, like indicated on the documentation:
`Note: If you need to dynamically manage and create event ticket, we recommend that you use the Web API to automate the creation of Event classes.` [LINK](https://developers.google.com/wallet/tickets/events/web/prerequisites)
So I went to see to dynamically create classes [right here](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/rest/v1/eventticketclass/insert), but I don't know how to post on this API and get the result, I tried to learn about gRPC Transcoding syntax, but I don't understand anything.
I hope to find my solution here, and someone will help me or already tried to do this? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I installed the gRPC lib for PHP, but I don't know how to do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok my bad, I just found the google repo on the API wallet after 5 hours of searching! https://github.com/google-pay/wallet-samples/blob/main/php/demo_eventticket.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).